# How to find the path of a button in a web page

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

I'm scraping this page:

http://www.bbb.org/atlanta/business-reviews/heating-and-air-conditioning/cool-flame-heating-and-air-in-powder-springs-ga-1009/customer-reviews?cacheit=y

and need to press the button to see the reviews.

with chrome  I get this path

```
//*[@id="myspanpos"]
```

But when I try the scrip:

```
NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH = '//*[@id="myspanpos"]'
button = browser.find_element_by_xpath(NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH)
button.click()
```

got:

```
 Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[text()=\"myspanpos\"]"}
```

Comment: strange, what happened if you try browser.find_element_by_id('myspanpos')

Comment: got this: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"myspanpos"}
Stacktrace:

Comment: that looks bad, i would test your script with a simple website first. maybe there is another problem with your code or the used library-versions. good luck ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open "Reviews" drop-down window you need to click on anchor tag element (`<a>`), not on `<span>`. So use

```
browser.find_element_by_id('close_open').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Selenium IDE and I got `id=customer-reviews` for ID, `css=#customer-reviews` for CSS path and `//a[contains(text(),'customer reviews')]` for xpath. I ran my Selenium IDE script where it clicks the customer reviews and it works.

Comment: with  '//a[contains(text(),'customer reviews')]' I don't get errors, but don't get any result neither

Comment: So the xpath problem is solved now? What exactly are you trying to achieve with your program?

Comment: I'm trying to get the text of reviews like this: "Cool Flame Heating & Air, Inc. has been my servicing provider since the mid 1990's. Doug is dependable, knowledgeable and honest" But I can't get the text untill I press the butto

Answer (score 0):

Found 2 problems:

1. Given xpath **contains {"}**. This is not valid xpath. You should use `//*[@id='myspanpos']` xpath.
2. "**customer reviews**" button is already selected. so If you click on that link/button it will redirect to same page. So you need to get next step after click on that link/button.

Note : Try to execute with wait/sleep for more impact. Example

```
NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH = '//*[@id='myspanpos']'
button = browser.find_element_by_xpath(NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH)
button.click()
#Your wait or sleep statment
```